# How to fill the array of integers from console input

Tags: c#, arrays, input, console

Let's say I know how many numbers will user put in. I have an int array and I want to fill it with integers user put in devided by particular character, for example space. I managed to solve it this way.

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(input[i]);
```

I want to ask you, is there any other, better way to do this?

Comment: Is this just homework?  Because there is no practical reason for what you are trying, without some kind of error trapping.

Comment: it's only to improve algorithmic thinking. of course in real program i would check for any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq:

```
var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(token => int.Parse(token));

// if you must have it as an array...
int[] arr = numbers.ToArray();
```

This basically does the same thing as your code, it's just more concise.

You could also make your code more robust by handling cases where the user inputs something that's not a number (which would cause `int.Parse()` to throw an exception).

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion 1:** if you would like to read all values from single line delimited by `space`, then i would suggest you to use `command line arguments`. so that you can atleast avoid using String array in your program as command line arguments are stored into the `Main()` method String array argument.

**Suggestion 2:** while parsing the values into Int it would be nice to check wether parsing is successfull or not, so that if the parsing failes(due to invalid integer) then we can store zero or some default value.

`Int32.TryParse()` allows you to let you know wether parsing is sucessfull or not.

Try This:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int[] numbers = new int[args.Length];
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<args.Length;i++)
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(args[i],out temp))
        {
            numbers[i] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            numbers[i] = 0;
        }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try, just read console line and split by space. use ConvertAll method fro Array class.

```
int[] myArray = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the return value from `Console.Read()` returns an integer, it isn't quite that simple. It will return the integer representation of the characters you type in.

In order to retrieve the number of elements, as your code attempts to do. You should refactor a small portion into this:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter no of elements");
c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Please note that this piece of code can throw exceptions if what you type in isn't a number

Answer (score -1):

You can use StringTokenizer to tokenize the whole line and then use parseInt().